# Unschedulable 0/1 nodes are available insufficient ephemeral-storage

Tags: kubernetes, workflow, amazon-eks

I have one strange issue.

The error that I'm getting is:

```
unschedulable 0/1 nodes are available insufficient ephemeral-storage
```

My requests per workflow that I run in kubernetes are:

```
resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: 50Gi
        memory: 8Gi
```

And my node capacity is 100GiB per node.

When I run `kubectl describe node <node-name>` I get the following result:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests    Limits
  --------                    --------    ------
  cpu                         125m (3%)   0 (0%)
  memory                      8Gi (55%)   0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage           50Gi (56%)  0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0           0
```

Do ephemeral-storage and memory overlap? What can be the issue? I cannot resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `kubectl describe node` output, Kubernetes believes it's used 50 GiB of disk ("ephemeral storage") and that's 56% of the available resources.  That implies there's about 89 GiB of usable disk space, and about 39 GiB left, so less space than your container claims it needs.

If the node has a 100 GiB disk, space required by the operating system, Kubernetes, and any pulled images counts against that disk capacity before being considered available for ephemeral storage.  You probably will never be able to run two Pods that both require 50 GiB of disk; with the OS overhead they will not both fit at the same time.

(It's also not impossible that the node has 100 GB and not 100 GiB storage.  100 * 10^9 is only 93 * 2^30, which would make that overhead about 4 GiB, which feels a little more typical to me.)

The easiest and "most Kubernetes" option here is to get another node, maybe via the cluster autoscaler.  If you do control the node configuration, changing nodes to more like 120 GB storage would make these Pods fit better.  Especially in an AWS/EKS context, current Kubernetes also supports [generic ephemeral volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/#generic-ephemeral-volumes) which would let you get per-pod storage backed by a volume (on AWS, most likely an EBS volume) rather than fixed-size local disk.

Comment: Adding a little bit more space to a nodegroup solved the issue. Thanks.